# Do I need any server in Docker container to run my Java app?

Tags: java, docker, selenium, maven

I have simple Maven based app with Sikuli, Selenium and JUnit. In assumption this app should be triggered by continous delivery of main application (which I'm testing) with Jenkins.

Should I use some embedded Java server like Tomcat in Spring Boot or maybe pure Java will be OK?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in running application inside docker or outside it in terms of application server and web server. Forget about Docker for a moment and answer this question:

Does your application need web server or application server to run on(outside docker).

If the answer is yes it will need web server to run on inside Docker either, And if the answer is no you can run it inside Docker container without using web server either.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, in order to run your application, you don't need a server, you didn't implement a web application and you don't serve anything through an api. you just run some tests. So I think the answer is no. Also check Jsoup, I think is really good framework